# Is it possible to add centering and vspace to the caption text of a figure?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, captions

I have a figure containing a pair of plots that represent data points from 15 referenced papers (indicated in the plots as 1-15).  To better indicate the source of each data point, I have added numbered list of the referenced papers at the bottom of the caption within an array as such.

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
$\begin{array}{c@{\hspace{0.1in}}c}
\includegraphics[width=2.8in]{./figures/SimoArea} &
\includegraphics[width=2.8in]{./figures/SimoAreaPerOutput}\\
(a) & (b)\\
\end{array}$
\caption[
A comparison of various SIMO DC-DC voltage converter designs.
]
{
A comparison of various single-inductor multiple-output DC-DC voltage converter designs across five technology generations: 
$0.5 \mu m$, $0.35 \mu m$, $0.25 \mu m$, $0.18 \mu m$, $0.13 \mu m$. 
(a) Design area verse voltage outputs. (b) Area per output for each design.
\\
{\protect
\vspace{0.5em}
%\centering
%\begin{center}
\tiny{
    $\begin{array}{lll}
        \text{1: Woo 2-Output Buck/Boost~\cite{woo:dcdc}} &
        \text{6: Seol 5-Output Buck/Boost~\cite{seol:multiple-output}} & 
        \text{11: Belloni 4-Output Buck~\cite{belloni:buck}}
        \\ 
        \text{2: Ma 2-Output Boost~\cite{ma:simo-discontinuos,ma:reduction}} &
        \text{7: Belloni 2-Output Buck~\cite{belloni:on-design}} &
        \text{12: Parayandeh 4-Output Buck~\cite{parayandeh:programmable}}
        \\ 
        \text{3: Belloni 4-Output Boost~\cite{belloni:self-boosted}} &
        \text{8: Lee 6-Output Buck~\cite{lee:simo}} &
        \text{13: Belloni 2-Output Buck~\cite{belloni:on-design}}
        \\ 
        \text{4: Belloni 4-Output Buck~\cite{belloni:on-design}} &
        \text{9: Huang 4-Output Buck/Boost~\cite{huang:simo}} &
        \text{14: Zhang 2-Output Boost~\cite{zhang:simo}}
        \\ 
        \text{5: Le 5-Output Boost~\cite{le:simo}} &
        \text{10: Bondade 3-Output Buck/Boost~\cite{bondade:codesign}} &
        \text{15: Bondade 2-Output Buck~\cite{bondade:power-aware}}
    \end{array}$
} % end tiny
%\end{center}
} % end protect

}
\label{fig:simo-area}
\end{figure*}
```

I would like to add a little vertical space between my reference list and the formal caption and also center the array containing this list (without centering the rest of the caption).  I have had no success so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply put the list (using `tabular`, not `array`!) below the caption and not make it part of it. I can't check on the correct alignment because you didn't mentioned the exact class or option you are using for your paper.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{0.1in}}c}
\includegraphics[width=2.8in]{./figures/SimoArea} &
\includegraphics[width=2.8in]{./figures/SimoAreaPerOutput}\\
(a) & (b)\\
\end{tabular}
\caption[
A comparison of various SIMO DC-DC voltage converter designs.
]
{
A comparison of various single-inductor multiple-output DC-DC voltage converter designs across five technology generations: 
$0.5 \mu m$, $0.35 \mu m$, $0.25 \mu m$, $0.18 \mu m$, $0.13 \mu m$. 
(a) Design area verse voltage outputs. (b) Area per output for each design.
}
\label{fig:simo-area}
\bigskip
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    g1: Woo 2-Output Buck/Boost~\cite{woo:dcdc} &
    g6: Seol 5-Output Buck/Boost~\cite{seol:multiple-output} & 
    g11: Belloni 4-Output Buck~\cite{belloni:buck}
    \\ 
    g2: Ma 2-Output Boost~\cite{ma:simo-discontinuos,ma:reduction} &
    g7: Belloni 2-Output Buck~\cite{belloni:on-design} &
    g12: Parayandeh 4-Output Buck~\cite{parayandeh:programmable}
    \\ 
    g3: Belloni 4-Output Boost~\cite{belloni:self-boosted} &
    g8: Lee 6-Output Buck~\cite{lee:simo} &
    g13: Belloni 2-Output Buck~\cite{belloni:on-design}
    \\ 
    g4: Belloni 4-Output Buck~\cite{belloni:on-design} &
    g9: Huang 4-Output Buck/Boost~\cite{huang:simo} &
    g14: Zhang 2-Output Boost~\cite{zhang:simo}
    \\ 
    g5: Le 5-Output Boost~\cite{le:simo} &
    g10: Bondade 3-Output Buck/Boost~\cite{bondade:codesign} &
    g15: Bondade 2-Output Buck~\cite{bondade:power-aware}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using package `subfig` makes more sense here, instead of `array`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% delete demo 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{}c@{\hspace{0.1in}}c@{}}
\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{./figures/SimoArea} &
\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{./figures/SimoAreaPerOutput}\\
(a) & (b)\\
\end{array}$
\caption[A comparison of various SIMO DC-DC voltage converter designs.]{%
  A comparison of various single-inductor multiple-output DC-DC voltage converter designs across five technology generations: 
  $0.5 \mu m$, $0.35 \mu m$, $0.25 \mu m$, $0.18 \mu m$, $0.13 \mu m$. 
  (a) Design area verse voltage outputs. (b) Area per output for each design.
\newline\strut\newline
\tiny
   \begin{tabular}{@{}lll}
        1: Woo 2-Output Buck/Boost~\cite{woo:dcdc} &
        6: Seol 5-Output Buck/Boost~\cite{seol:multiple-output} & 
        11: Belloni 4-Output Buck~\cite{belloni:buck}
        \\ 
        2: Ma 2-Output Boost~\cite{ma:simo-discontinuos,ma:reduction} &
        7: Belloni 2-Output Buck~\cite{belloni:on-design} &
        12: Parayandeh 4-Output Buck~\cite{parayandeh:programmable}
        \\ 
        3: Belloni 4-Output Boost~\cite{belloni:self-boosted} &
        8: Lee 6-Output Buck~\cite{lee:simo} &
        13: Belloni 2-Output Buck~\cite{belloni:on-design}
        \\ 
        4: Belloni 4-Output Buck~\cite{belloni:on-design} &
        9: Huang 4-Output Buck/Boost~\cite{huang:simo} &
        14: Zhang 2-Output Boost~\cite{zhang:simo}
        \\ 
        5: Le 5-Output Boost~\cite{le:simo} &
        10: Bondade 3-Output Buck/Boost~\cite{bondade:codesign} &
        15: Bondade 2-Output Buck~\cite{bondade:power-aware}
    \end{tabular}}
\label{fig:simo-area}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works well but I'm not getting the centering in mine (or the justification you seem to have).  I suspect it has something to do with the .sty file I'm using.  Since it's provided by the school per thesis requirements, I'm not certain where the disconnect is.

Comment: Provide the style file, then we can see more ...